# Selecting radio button in js

Tags: html, ajax, forms, radio-button

I have a problem in my code, I wanna show input text form when I click one of radio button.
Ajax code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#macam').click( function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
        if(value == "0"){
            $("#hilang").html("<input name='' value='tes' type='text'  />");
        }
        else{
            $("#hilang").html("");
        }
}); 
}); 
</script>
```

HTML code :

```
<input id="macam"  type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked></input>
<input id="macam"  type="radio" name="radio" value="0"></input>
    <div id="hilang"></div>
```

Comment: Have you included jQuery library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't reuse ids

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name="radio"]').click( function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
        if(value == "0"){
            $("#hilang").html("<input name='' value='tes' type='text'  />");
        }
        else{
            $("#hilang").html("");
        }
}); 
});
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="macam1"  type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked></input>
<input id="macam0"  type="radio" name="radio" value="0"></input>
<div id="hilang"></div>
```

Comment: the code works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/kfvuhhno/ are you including jquery? your question says ajax but you have shown no ajax code.

Answer (score 0):

Id should be unique. Change it to class.

***HTML***

```
<input class="macam"  type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked></input>
 <input class="macam"  type="radio" name="radio" value="0"></input>
<div id="hilang"></div>
```

***jQuery***

```
$('.macam').click( function() {
var value = $(this).val();
    if(value == 0){
        $("#hilang").html("<input name='' value='tes' type='text'  />");
    }
    else{
        $("#hilang").html("");
    }
});
```

Comment: value == "0" would have still worked because it would try and convert it to an int anyway. value === "0" would not have worked

Comment: I stand corrected. the value being returned is a string .... so (value === "0") works, but (value === 0) wont work

Answer (score 0):

First problem that jumps out is that you have two identical ID's. Declare your two radios class="macam" instead of id="macam" and use $(".macam") to select those classes instead of $("#.maca")

Use this instead

```
var value = $('input[name="radio"]:checked').val();
```

use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   $('.macam').click( function() {
    var value = $('input[name="radio"]:checked').val();
    if(value === "0"){
        $("#hilang").html("<input name='' value='tes' type='text'  />");
    }
    else{
        $("#hilang").html("");
    }
   }); 
 }); 
</script>

<input class="macam"  type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked></input>
<input class="macam"  type="radio" name="radio" value="0"></input>
    <div id="hilang"></div>
```

Comment: please give me full script, i'm confusing.. help me :'(